# Cannot run any files on Ubuntu 16.04: "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: files, binary

I am trying to run a few files that I have used before. When I try to execute,

```
./desire-cli getblockcount
```

it just gives me the error

```
-bash: ./desire-cli: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

It worked for me just fine a bit earlier. Now I can't run anything anymore. None of the commands work for any of the files.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Update:

```
file desire-cli
./desire-cli: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=bb64c90cef4152bbedaa6aaf04163daf35245533, stripped
```

Comment: Please update your post with output of `file ./desire-cli`.

Comment: Which CPU `arch` your Ubuntu have? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit? If it is 32-bit, the executable will not launch.

Comment: uname -m gives me an answer of "aarch64". I have used this file before successfully, but it doesn't work anymore for some reason. None of my files do. Even other programs.

Comment: It seems that `desire-cli` is compiled for *x86_64*, but your system has *aarch64* (ARM).  May be you have desire-cli compiled for ARM in different directory.

Comment: Yeah I actually made that mistake. But now I have the same problem with a file called "sentinel-lin64" and uname -m just says
uname: extra operand ‘sentinel-lin64’
Try 'uname --help' for more information.

Comment: Just try `file sentinel-lin64` instead of `uname -m sentinel-lin64`.

Comment: sentinel-lin64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=fdb92fd0de3892fc2176220c6694f8eee61d4fa3, stripped

If it's wrong, I do have access to the tar.gz source code file, but I don't really know how to compile it. Would that work?